# Get output of previously run rake task

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a rake task, that depends on another in terms of that it parses its output to determine failure or success.

Currently I do it like this:

```
task :foo do
  puts "OK"
end

task :bar do
  if `bundle exec rake foo`.split(/\n/)[-1] == "OK" then
    puts "Everything went fine"
  else
    puts "Something went wrong"
    exit 1
  end
end
```

But I would prefer not to run the dependency in a subshell but specify it correctly as in `task bar: :foo do` and then check its output, is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this, it calls one task from other. It helps.

```
namespace :abc do
  task :aa do
    "ok"
  end

  task :bb do
    op = Rake::Task["abc:aa"].enhance(["abc:aa"])
    p "op=> #{op}"
  end
end
```

Comment: That's definitely cleaner than my way. I'll wait a day or two until I accept, maybe some other answers come up in that time?

Comment: Looking some other answer too. Lets see. +1